# puppeteer: dynamic page using indexeddb not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to take a screenshot of a page that uses indexeddb to generate some of its content.

My puppeteer code is pretty simple:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 1080
    });
    const relevantSite = 'http://example.com'; // <<-- replace this with the actual site
    await page.goto(relevantSite);
    await page.waitForSelector('#myContentSelector');
    console.log('Content is now loaded');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'dynamic-screenshot.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This code above works fine for pages that dynamically generate content and **DON'T use indexeddb** but for pages that do, I just can't seem to figure out what I need to do in order to get the page to load correctly.

Do I have to do something special to get this **indexeddb** to work for headless pages loaded in puppeteer?

Comment: I feel your pain,I've been fighting with puppeteer the past weeks (but havent touched indexddb). I would try to set the userDataDir option (maybe you need it for indexedDb?). Also `dumpio:true` might give some hints. Are you using any babel transpiler or similar? If so make sure your async/awaits are real async awaits (check over current node version and transpile targets). Try puppeteer next-branch 
 (currently 1.5.0-next.1530333501924). Test headless false (but that's like the first thing anyone does). Open the site with chromium and check it's not a browser issue. Try a later node version.

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB seems to work just fine with puppeteer. [Example.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1784)

I suspect your issue is actually that you don't give the page time to load, and for the content to be populated.

```
await page.waitForSelector('#myContentSelector');
```

Is #myContentSelector something like a container div, where the actual content is populated later (even 25ms later)

Try waiting a second after the page loads before taking the screenshot?

Comment: `#myContentSelector` is a dynamically generated element. What ends up happening is that the `page.waitForSelector('#myContentSelector');` line never resolves for me and times out.

Comment: In short, I don't believe waiting will fix my issue (I've tried).

Comment: Try some different kinds of wait. networkidle0 works pretty reliable for me. Or your could wait for whichever is faster: `await Promise.race([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
  ]);`

Comment: @ippi Thanks for the suggestions, those were there first things I tried :S, I get the feeling that waiting isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try follow like:**

```
await page.goto(relevantSite, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
await page.waitForSelector('#myContentSelector');
console.log('Content is now loaded');
await page.screenshot({path: 'dynamic-screenshot.png'});
await navigationPromise;
```

Using options waitUntil for [`page.goto`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) and with [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but waitUntil options are the first things I tried and I can verify that this does not work :(